# flutter WebViewController how add header

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview

In my application i used WebViewController. But I don't know, how to pass a parameter to the header. This showing an error. How do I pass the parameter correctly? Please, help

```
class _PostRouteScreenState extends State<PostRouteScreen> {
final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
 @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://....../make-route',
headers:{"SB-app": "iphone"},
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
         _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
          print('allowing navigation to $request');
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) async {
          print('Page started loading: $url');
        },
        onPageFinished: (String url) async {
          print('Page finished loading: $url');
        },
        gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
      ),
```

Answer (score 4):

Try omitting the initialURL and using the controller which allows you to pass headers:

```
  body: WebView(
    // initialUrl: 'https://....../make-route',
    // headers: {"SB-app": "iphone"},
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
      _controller.complete(webViewController);
      webViewController.loadUrl(
        'https://....../make-route',
        headers: {"SB-app": "iphone"},
      );
    },
```